# Store all dates between 2 dates in vba into an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, date

I am using a function to get all dates between 2 dates in a list of Start Dates and End Dates: I am looking to store in an array each of the dates from start to end date with their unique ID. Data is column 1 ID, 2 Start Date, 3 End Date. The array would be a list of ID's with all pertaining dates from Start Date to End Date. Below is the code I have to get all dates:

```
Sub Test_Dates()
'
Dim TESTWB As Workbook
Dim TESTWS As Worksheet

Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")

For i = 2 To TESTWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

DatesTest = getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3))

Next i

End Sub


Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant

    Dim varDates()      As Date
    Dim lngDateCounter  As Long

    ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))

    For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
        varDates(lngDateCounter) = CDate(StartDate)
        StartDate = CDate(CDbl(StartDate) + 1)
    Next lngDateCounter

    getDates = varDates

ClearMemory:
    If IsArray(varDates) Then Erase varDates
    lngDateCounter = Empty
```

Comment: What is the issue your experiencing with your code?

Comment: The code works, but I do not know how to store the values found by getDates into an array

Comment: I see.  I would use a collection and have the key as the id and the return from your function as the item?

Comment: I've tried that but how to add items for each iteration of getdates?

Comment: `collection.add getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3)), cstr(TESTWS.Cells(i, 1))`  the retrieve like `collection(key)`   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works but am not sure how to search items by referencing the key? would something like For Each Key In DatesTest work in this case?

Comment: If you had an ID of ABC123, you would use CollectionName("ABC123"), you can loop through all using foreach, have a look at the link i attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an array with the size of the rows `ReDim DatesTest(1 To LastRow - FirstRow + 1)` and fill that with your results from `getDates`.

```
Dim TESTWB As Workbook
Dim TESTWS As Worksheet

Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")

Const FirstRow As Long = 2
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = TESTWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

Dim DatesTest() As Variant
ReDim DatesTest(1 To LastRow - FirstRow + 1)

Dim i As Long
For i = FirstRow To LastRow
    DatesTest(i - FirstRow + 1) = getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3))
Next i
```

You can then access the first result of `getDates` with `DatesTest(1)` where `DatesTest(1)(1)` should give you the first date of the first set.

If you want to loop through all of them you can do it like that:

```
Dim DateSet As Variant
For Each DateSet In DatesTest  ' loop through all sets of dates
    Dim DateItem As Variant
    For Each DateItem In DateSet  ' loop through all dates of one set
        Debug.Print DateItem
    Next DateItem
Next DateSet
```

or like

```
Dim iSet As Long
For iSet = 1 To Ubound(DatesTest)  ' loop through all sets of dates
    Dim iDate As Long
    For iDate = 0 To Ubound(DatesTest(iSet))  ' loop through all dates of one set
        Debug.Print "Set " & iSet, "Date " & DatesTest(iSet)(iDate)
    Next iDate
Next iSet
```

This should output something like

```
Set 1        Date 2022-03-08
Set 1        Date 2022-03-09
Set 1        Date 2022-03-10
Set 2        Date 2022-04-01
Set 2        Date 2022-03-02
Set 2        Date 2022-03-03
…
```

---

If you want to use the `ID(i,1)` as key then you need to use a `Collection` instead of an array.

```
Dim TESTWB As Workbook
Dim TESTWS As Worksheet

Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")

Const FirstRow As Long = 2
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = TESTWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

DatesTest As New Collection

Dim i As Long
For i = FirstRow To LastRow
    DatesTest.Add getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3)), TESTWS.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
```

Then you can use `DatesTest(TESTWS.Cells(2, 1))` to get the first set of dates and `DatesTest(TESTWS.Cells(2, 1))(1)` would give you the first date of that set.

Comment: Thanks works well - how could I make DatesTest(1) = the ID (i,1)?

Comment: see my edit. You cannot set `DatesTest(1) =  ID (i,1)` because `DatesTest(1)` is the entire array result of `getDates(TESTWS.Cells(1, 2), TESTWS.Cells(1, 3))`. But you can use a `Collection` ind use the ID as a key.

Comment: DatesTest.Add getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3)), ID(i, 1) the ID(i,1) does not work unfortunately, but I can add it with DatesTest.Add getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3)), CStr(TESTWS.Cells(i, 1)) I think, otherwise how to refer to it as ID?

Comment: @Florian I don't know where your ID is so I can't help you with this

Comment: the ID is in TESTWS.Cells(i, 1) I would like to use it as the key to search items in the collection, it is just a random number sequence

Comment: @Florian see my edit then

Comment: Yes that should work...will figure out how to use the key. Thanks.

Comment: @Florian See [The Ultimate Guide To Collections in Excel VBA](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/) for how to use collections with keys. It explains pretty much everything that you can do with collections.

Comment: @PEH I have gone for the array solution finally as it is more flexible, but would you know if it is possible to make it 2 dimensional? ie for DatesTest(1)(1) for ex make the second value a second dimension? otherwise I am not sure how to loop for DatesTest(1)(1 to 4) for ex

Comment: See my edit how to loop through the dates